# Compile C File Using Makefile On Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, makefile

I have a project with a `.c` file and a `Makefile` containing "compilation rules" for the `gcc` compiler. I'm having trouble finding a way to compile it into an executable on my `Windows 8` machine. It was straight-forward on `Ubuntu`.

It should also be as simple as installing `gcc` and using the command line to switch to that directory and using the `make` command.

I'm stuck at the installation part since I can't find an easy or well documented solution.

Please suggest me a piece of software for this task. I do need step-by-step instructions to make the `make` command available on the command line globally using e.g. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) since it doesn't do it itself nor tells anything about it.

Comment: Have you heard of [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)? It's very likely the answer to all your woes. Use it to install gcc, gmake, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the PATH variable so it includes the directory for your MinGW binaries:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
...;D:\bin-win64\mingw64\bin;...
```

For more information, see

https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8